# MongoDB cast error in _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose.
My schema is like

```
var tblTypes = new Schema({
_id: { type: String, required: true }
, desc: String
, priority: Number  
}, { collection: 'tblTypes' });
```

while fetching records in the query i am giving like dis as query in findone

**JSON**

```
{ _id: "SFK" }
```

Its giving

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "CONFIRM" at path "_id"',
name: 'CastError',
type: 'ObjectId',
value: 'CONFIRM',
path: '_id' }
```

as error. Earlier its working in different system.
I am not sure about both the versions.
Where i am going wrong ?

Comment: I'm wondering where "CONFIRM" even comes from, given that you're querying with "JFK".  Are you sure the error is coming from the query?  Is there a pre init hook that might be the culprit?  Did the schema for this or another model using the same collection *change to* ObjectId *from* String?  I tried to recreate a situation like this, but couldn't reproduce a cast error (in mongoose 2 or 3).

Comment: Yeah i got it.Its some other stupid error i made.
Its working fine.
How to make this question is solved ?
please help for that

Comment: Perhaps you can describe your error, how you solved it and mark it as answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved).